# C# matching two text files then copying out

Tags: c#

What I have going on is two files, one file contains:

Orange
Apple

The second file contains
Orange~1.txt
Orange~2321.txt
Apple~12.txt
Apple~23.txt
Ap~23.txt
OROR~23.txt

What I need to do is is if the first file matches a line in the second file, copy that file out to a new directory.   What I have going on now never finds any matching items.

```
string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Cact.txt");
            string[] mastercontent = File.ReadAllLines(masterdin + "\\Master.txt");
            foreach (string con in content)
            {
                if (mastercontent.Contains(con))
                {
                    File.Copy(masterfolder + "\\" + con, masterdin);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the LINQ `Contains` method on the array, which will return true if the array contains a string which is exactly equal to `con`.

The simplest solution is to change `mastercontent` to a single string by calling `File.ReadAllText`.
This will call `String.Contains`, and will check whether `con` appears anywhere in the large string. (This would behave differently if `con` has newlines, but it can't)

Alternatively, you can use LINQ to check whether `mastercontent` has any strings containing `con`, like this:

```
if (mastercontent.Any(m => m.Contains(con))
```

**EDIT**: To match case-insensitively, you can change it to the following:

```
if (mastercontent.Any(m => 0 >= m.IndexOf(con, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```